# CRM 2011 Contact Address Set up for Both Domestic and Internationl

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011

Great community here!

I am currently working within a 2011 CRM system that has a new requirement of the end users updating Contact Addresses from domestic (US) addressing to International. The system was originally set up for just Domestic addresses.

My problems are with the Telephone field and zip code. Both have custom javascript to format the integers in the field and ensure length compliance.

Now, is it possible to manipulate the JavaScript below to handle the both domestic and international phone numbers?

Below is the function that is called on an onchange event:

```
function checkPhoneNumberFormat(obj) {
var phoneNumber = obj.getEventSource().getValue();

if (phoneNumber != null) {
    var sTmp = phoneNumber.replace(/[^0-9]/g, "");

    switch (sTmp.length) {
        case 10:
            obj.getEventSource().setValue("(" + sTmp.substr(0, 3) + ") " + sTmp.substr(3, 3) + "-" + sTmp.substr(6, 4));
            break;

        default:
            alert("Phone must contain 10 numbers.");
            break;
    }
}
```

}

Somewhat new to java scripting, just looking for some feed back, on how to manipulate this code. It would be great if it had the ability to auto format 9 digit as well as 14 digit phone numbers. And only allow numbers of those lengths to be passed through on the save.

Any comments or ideas are greatly appreciated.

Thank You!

Comment: You could put in a condition based on the country field, and simply don't try and format those fields if not in the US. If you want to format phone numbers for every country, you will have your work cut out - the UK for example has at least 3 main formats for the grouping of digits in phone numbers, and I suspect the number of combinations could be prohibitive. You may be best to format all non-domestic numbers as a straight string with no spaces or punctuation

Comment: Formatting all as one string is a great idea! Would it be possible to format the JavaScript above to allow this as of right now it requires 10 digits and auto formats. It is possible to manipulate the Script above to auto format 10 digit numbers, but allow up to 14 in just a straight string? Thank You for the reply!

Answer (score 0):

Yes Pawel, this is pretty simple to do:
put another case statement like this (this means do nothing, but don't throw that alert up when the length is 14, since you don't want to do any special formatting)

```
case 14: 
    break;
```

Then in your onsave - you can do the same thing but block saving in the "Default" case.

```
default:
alert("Phone number must contain 10 or 14 digits");
executionObj.getEventArgs().preventDefault();
break;
```

One thing to note about phone numbers is that often there can be extensions, this doesn't seem to be handled by your code, but maybe that is not relevant to your application.